# PayPal. Charge a security deposit

Tags: api, transactions, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I was wondering If I could charge a "security deposit" using PayPal ?

On my site, user can pay for an item (service). But I have no idea, how to charge a security deposit, because it is NOT guaranteed that user will pay using his PayPal account - That way I could simply use MassPay API to refund the deposit back to the user (payer_email).

But, PayPal allows to pay even without creating an account. Although, user has to specify his email address, I'm not sure that sending back money to this email address would put the money on related credit/debit card.

Is there some API for doing this ? Because charging price for the item + security deposit doesn't feel right for me.

I know that, for example, airbnb.com has some similair functionality for that one, but I don't know how it works

I would be very grateful if someone helped me with that one.

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue - for a holiday cottage. The only solution I have come-up with is to charge the weekly rent, then add on a security deposit - so charge in one amount / one transaction. Then assuming all is good at the end of the rental, do a 'partial' refund which would cost me 20 pence GBP. But would like to know any other options / api's. Ideally I would like to to take your CC / Debit Card details and then auto-charge you if you trashed the place (as you have agreed to my T's & C's) - a bit like a car hire company does. Is this possible? All help much appreciated

Comment: "Refund" you mean as a PayPal function ?
Not a bad solution, actually. I didn't come with anything better, unfortunately. 
Thank you for an idea!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your primary issue is that users can checkout without a PayPal account.  If that's the case, this can easily be solved by disabling the "PayPal Account Optional" feature in your PayPal profile under Website Payment Preferences.  This will causes users to either sign in to PayPal or create an account to pay.

If you'd rather leave that option enabled there are plenty of ways to handle security deposits and returning money, each with their own advantages and disadvantages.  I won't get into all those details yet, though, if simply disabling that option solves your issue.

Let me know if you want more info on the other options.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I found an "Authorize & Capture" API. But I still don't understand how to make 2 separate payments: 1) The main price is paid immediately. 2) Security Deposit will get held reserved just right after it.